# Scraping Data Using BeautifulSoup for each subpage - url really long & different format

Tags: python, loops, url, beautifulsoup

I am scraping [NFL passing data](https://www.nfl.com/stats/player-stats/category/passing/2019/REG/all/passingyards/desc) for years 1971 to 2019. I was able to scrape the data on the first page of each year using this code:

```
# This code works:
passingData = []  # create empty list to store column data     
for year in range(1971,2020):
    url = 'https://www.nfl.com/stats/player-stats/category/passing/%s/REG/all/passingyards/desc' % (year)
    response = requests.get(url)
    response = response.content
    parsed_html = bsoup(response, 'html.parser')
    data_rows = parsed_html.find_all('tr')
    passingData.append([[col.text.strip() for col in row.find_all('td')] for row in data_rows])
```

The first page for each year only has 25 players, and roughly 70-90 players threw a pass each year (so there are between 3-4 pages of player data on "subpages" within each year). The problem comes when I try to scrape these subpages. I tried to add another sub-for-loop which pulls out the href of each link to the next page and append to the base url which is found in the **div class 'nfl-o-table-pagination__buttons'**

Unfortunately, I cannot add to the passingData list from the first page. I attempted the below, but 'Index Out of Range Error' occurred on the subUrl line.

I am still new to web scraping, so if my logic is way off please let me know. I figured I could just append the subpage data (since the table structure is the same), but seems the error arises when I attempt to go from:  
https://www.nfl.com/stats/player-stats/category/passing/%s/REG/all/passingyards/desc  
to the second page, which has url of : 
https://www.nfl.com/stats/player-stats/category/passing/2019/REG/all/passingYards/DESC?aftercursor=0000001900000000008500100079000840a7a000000000006e00000005000000045f74626c00000010706572736f6e5f7465616d5f737461740000000565736249640000000944415234363631343100000004726f6c6500000003504c5900000008736561736f6e496400000004323031390000000a736561736f6e5479706500000003524547f07fffffe6f07fffffe6389bd3f93412939a78c1e6950d620d060004

```
    for subPage in range(1971,2020):
        subPassingData = []
        subUrl = soup.select('.nfl-o-table-pagination__buttons a')[0]['href']
        new = requests.get(f"{url}{subUrl}")
        newResponse = new.content
        soup1 = bsoup(new.text, 'html.parser')
        sub_data_rows = soup1.find_all('tr')
        subPassingData.append([[col.text.strip() for col in row.find_all('td')] for row in data_rows])
        
    passingData.append(subPassingData)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script goes for all selected years and sub-pages and loads the data to dataframe (or you can save it to csv instead, etc...):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nfl.com/stats/player-stats/category/passing/{year}/REG/all/passingyards/desc'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

all_data = []

for year in range(2017, 2020):  # <-- change to desired year
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(year=year), headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    page = 1

    while True:
        print('Page {}/{}...'.format(page, year))

        for tr in soup.select('tr:has(td)'):
            tds = [year] + [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')]
            all_data.append(tds)

        next_url = soup.select_one('.nfl-o-table-pagination__next')
        if not next_url:
            break

        u = 'https://www.nfl.com' + next_url['href']
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
        page += 1


# here we create dataframe from the list `all_data` and print it to screen:
from pandas import pd
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
Page 1/2017...
Page 2/2017...
Page 3/2017...
Page 4/2017...
Page 1/2018...
Page 2/2018...
Page 3/2018...
Page 4/2018...
Page 1/2019...
Page 2/2019...
Page 3/2019...
Page 4/2019...
        0                   1     2    3    4    5      6   7   8      9   10     11  12  13  14  15   16
0    2017           Tom Brady  4577  7.9  581  385  0.663  32   8  102.8  230  0.396  62  10  64  35  201
1    2017       Philip Rivers  4515  7.9  575  360  0.626  28  10     96  216  0.376  61  12  75  18  120
2    2017    Matthew Stafford  4446  7.9  565  371  0.657  29  10   99.3  209   0.37  61  16  71  47  287
3    2017          Drew Brees  4334  8.1  536  386   0.72  23   8  103.9  201  0.375  72  11  54  20  145
4    2017  Ben Roethlisberger  4251  7.6  561  360  0.642  28  14   93.4  207  0.369  52  14  97  21  139
..    ...                 ...   ...  ...  ...  ...    ...  ..  ..    ...  ...    ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ...
256  2019      Trevor Siemian     3  0.5    6    3    0.5   0   0   56.3    0      0   0   0   3   2   17
257  2019       Blake Bortles     3  1.5    2    1    0.5   0   0   56.3    0      0   0   0   3   0    0
258  2019       Kenjon Barner     3    3    1    1      1   0   0   79.2    0      0   0   0   3   0    0
259  2019         Alex Tanney     1    1    1    1      1   0   0   79.2    0      0   0   0   1   0    0
260  2019          Matt Haack     1    1    1    1      1   1   0  118.8    1      1   0   0   1   0    0

[261 rows x 17 columns]
```

Comment: Perfect! It ran successfully. Thank you for putting it into a pandas df, which makes it much easier to concat the headers and save it. Thank you so much!